# Scientific meta analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, biostatistics, systematic-review

I will be analysing the effects of enzyme inhibitors on a certain enzyme on invivo and invitro animal and human cancer cell model lines as this enzyme is associated with pathogenicity; to assess whether targeting this enzyme with inhibitors can be a useful therapy for that cancer.

My problem is that, there are no participants, it will be invivo animal model and human cancer cell lines. And no control group. Some studies measure the % of metastasis invasion before and after treatment, and the reduction of metastasis before and after treatment. I may also be analysing the effects of ***several different enzymes inhibitors*** (or several different interventions).

What variables could I investigate for my statistical analysis?

I understand that if there is no control group, I have to do a meta-analysis of proportions? Please can someone help as I have never done a systematic review & meta analysis before and I hate statistics …